# How to change image in main-activity based on date in android application

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

Looking for an android application, that needs to change the image after day by day.

Example: If system date=01.01.2021 then image1 should be displayed else image2 should be displayed.

This is my android source code:

```
package com.wavedevelopers.chat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        Date now_date = null;
        cal.setTime(now_date);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.content);

        if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY)
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);
        }
        else if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.TUESDAY)
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a2);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: That looks right. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: this code check the day of the week and display the image but I need to check both  day and month and display the image..

Comment: Well you didn't ask that. Please see my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your work and response :) Can you make it 'DATE' instead of 'DAY_OF_WEEK'? it will be more helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Is this the answer you were looking for? If so, please consider marking my answer as the answer and hit to up arrow on any informative comments. Otherwise I'll be glad to help with any other questions.

Comment: if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY && cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.NOVEMBER)

Above code is used to validate DAY_OF_WEEK and MONTH, 

but i need to validate DATE AND MONTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    package com.wavedevelopers.chat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.content);

        if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY && cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.NOVEMBER)
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);
        }
        else if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.TUESDAY)
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a2);
        }
        else if(dayOfMonth == 1) {
            System.out.println("It's the first of the month")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your work and response :) Can you make it 'DATE' instead of 'DAY_OF_WEEK'? it will be more helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Added an additional 'else if' where the condition checks if it's the first of the month. But be aware, because the first condition is met (because today is monday and the month is September) none of the else statements will be checked.

Comment: Thank you for your response again, At last, I want code that validates Both  *DATE and MONTH* Example: If ( date and month = Local date) then display the Image.

Comment: Show me what you attempted and tell me where it isn't working.

Comment: if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY && cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.NOVEMBER)

Above code is used to validate DAY_OF_WEEK and MONTH, 

but i need to validate DATE AND MONTH